# Creating a signup process with AngularJS and NodeJS

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js

I want to create multiple page sign up process for my website.

So for instance, on one page, the user enters his name, and email, then clicks next and is presented with another page prompting for more data (i.e. his address, interests, etc).

I see that in Angular, it's possible to have blocks of HTML (the view) that are kept invisible by the `ng-show` tag until its decided to reveal them. I'm wondering if it's a good idea to simple put all of these data input pages in one HTML doc and reveal them when **`Next`** is clicked. Or is this a bad idea?

Also, I'd really appreciate if you can advise on how to integrate this with NodeJS and send the data the user enters up to the server. Should I wait until everything is entered and send one large `POST`? I guess this depends on how the Angular side of things is done.

I'd really appreciate any direction you can provide! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track. Both while using angular and node sending a single post request for submitting form have benefits.

> 1) About using Angular,

Put all of these data input pages in one HTML doc and reveal them when Next is clicked

I would have rather suggested to use localStorage for storing  different parts of the form and send them to the server only if you weren't using angular, but with angular
its is a good to show different parts of form with different views and then submit them as a single large json object once the form is completely filled , angular is used  for doing this single page application stuff.
here is a short tutorial for creating a multilevel signup form

http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/angularjs-multi-step-form-using-ui-router

> 2) About using node,

Node is asynchronous, and
There is only one main thread serving all your requests in node, so making less requests will definitely reduce load on your server
node can then complete your all database operations related to your form on a single request.